# How can we automate applications present on MAC appart from using Sikuli

Tags: macos, appium

Is it possible to d it with appium or any other tool please help me with your suggestions.Thanks

Comment: I'm working on an application in which i have to download multiple no. of files..

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Appium for Mac](https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac)

Its based on JSON wire protocol, so you can expect similar syntax to WebDriver/Appium tests.

Comment: But can it automate third party applications.for ex:skype

Comment: It should be possible, but its not a silver bullet. I suggest to read open issues and available docs https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac/issues/41